# mysql database monitoring strategy in production

Tags: mysql, database, database-administration, strategy-pattern

I m using MySQL as database for my project and in coming few weeks, we are migrating from dev to prod environment, so whats would be the plans to monitor the status of database in production environment?

Answer (score 0):

Enable mysql slow logs in mysql configuration , so that you can catch the mysql queries taking more time.

Also try newrelic.com , they have a good monitoring system. Its a paid one but useful.

Answer (score 0):

I will advise you to try [**MONyog MySQL Monitoring Tool**](https://www.webyog.com/).

I use it to Monitor our Production servers 24/7 on the go. It provides a “MySQL DBA in a box” experience that helps MySQL DBAs manage more MySQL servers, tune their current MySQL servers and find and fix problems with their MySQL database applications before they can become serious problems or costly outages.

It provides Real time Agent-less monitoring. It does quite a neat job as far as MySQL admin operations are concerned and has a great maintenance cycle. It also has a built in slow query analyzer feature.

[image]

You may check the video for more:

http://youtu.be/wi-EeudUL-c